# error al intentar acoplar reportviewer a un form c#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

me salta este error cuando intento acoplar un complemento NuGet, el control reportviewer...
a un formulario...
desde ya muchas gracias
utilizo vs2019 y es una aplicacion windows forms:
probe la solucion propuesta en otra pregunta ya hecha, pero no me funciono...
No se si tengo el problema por haber instalado y desinstalado el complemento NuGet, pero bueno agradezco sus opiniones.

[A]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer no puede convertirse en [B]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer. El tipo A se origina a partir de 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' en el contexto 'LoadNeither' en la ubicación 'C:\Users\Nelson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_ef3271d2\ProjectAssemblies\d4k6vzla01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'. El tipo B se origina a partir de 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' en el contexto 'LoadFrom' en la ubicación 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SSAS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'.

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve... hay que tener cuidado con las versiones del complemento Nugget rptviewer; de acuerdo a la version de visual studio que se utilice....

Answer (score -1):

Mira este link al parecer es una extensión la que está dando problemas https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1017992/reportviewer-winforms-problem-with-analysis-servic

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/407523)